# php rmdir or unlink file from folder

Tags: php, unlink, rmdir

The following code deletes the files in a folder `uploads`.How do I delete the folder as well when a user clicks `Delete Folder` (or similar).

I tried using `rmdir` but I am not getting errors only blank move.php file.

What's the correct/recommended way of doing it ? Please advice.

```
    <?php
    $actfolder = $_REQUEST['folder'];
    require_once("models/config.php");

    if(!securePage($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])){
        die();
    }
    require("models/db-settings.php");

    if(isset($_GET['file'])){
        $filename = "uploads/$loggedInUser->username$actfolder/" . ltrim($_GET['file'], '/\\');
        // make sure only deleting a file in files/ directory
        if (dirname(realpath($filename)) == realpath("uploads/$loggedInUser->username$actfolder/")) {
            unlink($filename);
        }
    }
    header("Location:".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
?>
```

Comment: Also pay attention to folder permissions. A folder must be empty of files and not only it must have correct permissions, but the parent folder must have these permissions too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try something like this:

```
$filename = "uploads/$loggedInUser->username$actfolder/";
if (is_dir($filename) === true)
    {
        $files = array_diff(scandir($filename), array('.', '..'));

        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
           unlink(realpath($filename) . '/' . $file);
        }

        rmdir($filename);  //remove directory
    }
```

Comment: deleted my other files not the folder :/

Comment: no worries works just added :` . ltrim($_GET['file'], '/\\') `  at the end of destination folde from my default code.